# Como manter coluna 'ordem' em sequência mesmo após uma edição da ordem de registros?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela com n campos, sendo que um deles é a 'ordem' (obviamente é sequencial: 1, 2, 3, n...):

```
id  |  ordem  | nome
------------------------
1   |  1      | Fabio
3   |  2      | Gilmar
2   |  3      | Rodrigo
9   |  4      | Marcos
```

Estou desenvolvendo um tabela drag and drop para alterar essa ordem, logo, como faço para manter sempre essa sequencia sem pular nenhum número e nem repeti-los?

Para dificultar um pouco, também haverá ordem manual, ou seja, o usuário acessa o registro e seleciona a posição desejada. Logo, deverá ser alterada todos os registros abaixo deste.

Obs: Meu sistema fornece 4 parâmetros após arrastar: id, direction (forward/back), fromPosition e toPosition que poderia ser utilizado na query.

Comment: Só para saber mesmo, vc só esta usando mysql ou esta usando alguma linguagem de programação para isso, tipo php, python, java, alguma outra coisa. Se for só no banco isso vc deverá ver sobre procedures e/ou triggers.

Comment: Estou usando php, mas ideia inicial era fazer a operação via banco de dados. Mas se houver uma solução via php será bem vinda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal seria você de alguma forma saber a ordem nova do item em questão, e fazer 2 *updates*:

```
update TABELA set ordem = ordem + 1 where ordem > 7 (para acrescentar 1 para os itens acima da nova ordem)

update TABELA set ordem = ordem - 1 where ordem < 7 and ordem <> 0 (para decrescer 1 para os itens abaixo da nova ordem)
```

Com isso a ordem 6 ficaria livre ... algo do tipo. Tem que ir mais ou menos por esse lado.

Answer (score 3):

Minha sugestão seria a coluna `ordem` não ser sequencial, e sim ser um campo que incrementa normalmente de 10.

Por exemplo:

```
id  |  ordem  | nome
------------------------
1   |  10     | Fabio
3   |  20     | Gilmar
2   |  30     | Rodrigo
9   |  40     | Marcos
```

Para trocar a posição, incremente a posição destino em 5:

```
id  |  ordem  | nome
------------------------
1   |  10     | Fabio
3   |  25     | Gilmar
2   |  30     | Rodrigo
9   |  40     | Marcos
```

Depois mova a posição de origem para a posição que foi mudada:

```
id  |  ordem  | nome
------------------------
1   |  10     | Fabio
9   |  20     | Marcos <-- update de ordem para 20
3   |  25     | Gilmar
2   |  30     | Rodrigo
```

Depois é só rebalancear as outras linhas:

```
id  |  ordem  | nome
------------------------
1   |  10     | Fabio
9   |  20     | Marcos
3   |  30     | Gilmar
2   |  40     | Rodrigo
```

Comment: É uma ótima abordagem, mas ainda assim, é necessário fazer um segundo update para normalização da ordem. Mas ainda assim, é uma abordagem fácil de entender e aplicar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você está arrastando nomes de uma posição para outra.
Neste caso você só precisaria de um par (Id, Ordem)Origem e (Id, Ordem)Destino.

Seguindo seu exemplo:

| id | ordem | nome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Fabio |
| 3 | 2 | Gilmar |
| 2 | 3 | Rodrigo |
| 9 | 4 | Marcos |

Ao arrastar Marcos para a posição Fabio
você faria um par de updates trocando as posições

```
update Tabela set Ordem = 4 where Id = 1
update Tabela set Ordem = 1 where Id = 9
```

Resultando em:

| id | ordem | nome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | Fabio |
| 3 | 2 | Gilmar |
| 2 | 3 | Rodrigo |
| 9 | 1 | Marcos |

Como tabelas de BD **não possuem ordem** intrínseca você (deveria sempre) declarar a ordenação.

```
Select Id, Ordem, Nome from Tabela order by Ordem
```

Dai seu resultado será sempre retornado corretamente.

**EDIT**

No caso de você querer arrastar um nome para uma posição e manter os outros em suas posições relativas é um pouco mais complicado.

Seguindo o exemplo de arrastar o Marcos para a posição do Fabio.
Você teria que setar o Marcos para ordem 1 e para todo mundo entre 1 e a antiga posição do Marcos incrementar de 1 (porquê você arrastou de baixo para cima).
Se modo semelhante arrastar o Fabio para a posição do Marcos você teria que setar o Fabio para 4 e decrementar a posição de todo mundo abaixo do Fábio até o Marcos

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um swap... pega o valor de fromPosition, usa esse valor para alterar o valor do da ordem do registro que está em toPosition, depois altera o registro que de fato foi mudado... dessa forma, você tem os registros simplesmente "trocados" um pelo outro, sem perder sua sequência.